# error : Could not resolve dependencies (maven javaEE project)

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, maven-2, netbeans7.0

I have a maven Entreprise application project . I create the persistence unit, an entity Class and an EJB Session Bean in the EJB project. I have this error when I try to build the project:

> Failed to execute goal on project Blog6-ejb: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project com.mycompany:Blog6-ejb:ejb:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The
>   following artifacts could not be resolved:
>   org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:jar:2.2.0,
>   org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:jar:2.0.3,
>   org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor:jar:2.2.0:
>   Failure to find org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:jar:2.2.0 in
>   http://ftp.ing.umu.se/mirror/eclipse/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo was
>   cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted
>   until the update interval of eclipselink has elapsed or updates are
>   forced -> [Help 1]

Here is the code in pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
<artifactId>Blog6</artifactId>
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>Blog6-ejb</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>ejb</packaging>

<name>Blog6-ejb</name>

<properties>
<endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<netbeans.hint.deploy.server>gfv3ee6</netbeans.hint.deploy.server>
</properties>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
<artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
<version>2.2.0</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
<version>2.0.3</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
<artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
<version>2.2.0</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>javax</groupId>
<artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
<version>6.0</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>4.8.2</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3.2</version>
<configuration>
<source>1.6</source>
<target>1.6</target>
<compilerArguments>
<endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
</compilerArguments>
</configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3</version>
<configuration>
<ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
</configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.1</version>
<executions>
<execution>
<phase>validate</phase>
<goals>
<goal>copy</goal>
</goals>
<configuration>
<outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
<silent>true</silent>
<artifactItems>
<artifactItem>
<groupId>javax</groupId>
<artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
<version>6.0</version>
<type>jar</type>
</artifactItem>
</artifactItems>
</configuration>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
<repository>
<url>http://ftp.ing.umu.se/mirror/eclipse/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo</url>
<id>eclipselink</id>
<layout>default</layout>
<name>Repository for library Library[eclipselink]</name>
</repository>
</repositories>
</project>
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="com.mycompany_Blog6-ejb_ejb_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU" transaction-type="JTA">
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<jta-data-source>jdbc/sample</jta-data-source>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<properties>
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 6):

> The use of the Eclipse mirrors for Maven repositories has been reported to cause varying issues from artifacts being reported as unavailable to local maven repository corruption. Therefore, instead of using the mirrored download URL: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?r=1&nf=1&file=/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo it is recommended that you use the unmirrored URL to directly access the EclipseLink Maven repository on the Eclipse download site instead: http://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo

Source & more info: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Maven Including how to edit your pom file to point to the different repo.

Comment: Thanks, I just replaced the URL in pom.xml by "http://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo" and it works

Comment: Good to hear! BTW, when you get an answer that works you should accept it. It makes people more likely to answer your questions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to create simple Java EE 6 application with persistence enabled you can start with provided artefacts, like for example this one:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=jboss-javaee6-webapp -DarchetypeGroupId=org.jboss.weld.archetypes -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.1.CR1 -DarchetypeRepository=central
```

or for simple servlets containers only:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=jboss-jsf-weld-servlet-webapp -DarchetypeGroupId=org.jboss.weld.archetypes -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.1.Beta1 -DarchetypeRepository=central
```

found here: http://seamframework.org/Documentation/CDIQuickstartForMavenUsers

after generating your project, import it into the IDE of your choice as an existing maven project.